# React Router not working when clicking on navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When I click on 'Cars' on the `Navbar` nothing happens.

Navbar

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar bg="navbar bg-primary" data-bs-theme="dark">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Cars4Rent</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link
                as={Link}
                to="/cars"
                onClick={() => console.log('Link Clicked')}
              >
                Cars
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/About">About</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/Support">Support</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/Register">Register</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/Login">Login</Nav.Link>        
            </Nav>

        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
function Cars() {
  return (
    <div className="cars">
      <h1>Car</h1>       
      <Container>
        <Row xs={2} md={4} lg={6}>
          <Col>1 of 2</Col>
          <Col>2 of 2</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row xs={1} md={2}>
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col>2 of 3</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row xs="auto">
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col>2 of 3</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cars;
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route> 
          <Route exact path="/cars">
            <Cars />
          </Route>
        </Switch>     
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried to change it to:

```
<Route path="/" exact>
  <Home />
</Route>
```

But then I get transferred to the cars page and can't get back to the home page.

I'm expecting to see the cars page but nothing changes. The onClicked method is working.

When I click on cars on the `Navbar` the link is `"http://localhost:3000/cars"`.

Comment: Your `exact` boolean flag on the Router of Home page was the correct edition. But the question is how did you try to get back from Cars to Home? By pressing the back button of the browser? or by pressing the Navbar button?

Answer (score 0):

Within the `Switch` component the ***first*** matched `Route` or `Redirect` is returned and rendered. You should order the routes in the inverse order of path spcecificity. In other words, order the routes from ***most*** specific to ***least*** specific. This allows paths like `"/cars"` to be matched before "falling back" to less specific paths like `"/"`.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/cars" component={Cars} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>     
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

If implemented correctly there is almost zero need for the `exact` prop to "disambiguate" a route. For example, if you *did* have a `NotFound` "catch-all" route then you *would* need to use the `exact` prop on the home route.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/cars" component={Cars} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>     
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: i tried implementing your solution and i get immediately transferred to Cars page and Home button is not working 
https://prnt.sc/fo8Y4loXKIoY

Comment: @Le_General_Kenobi Perhaps you have some routing/navigation issue elsewhere. The "Home" link is targeting `"/home"`, but you are not rendering a route on that path. The "home" component is on `"/"`. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: is there any other way to send you a demo? i'm having problems running my project on that website

Comment: @Le_General_Kenobi It doesn't look like you've a lot of code, you could probably copy/paste the relevant code into the sandbox. We'd just need a minimal example that runs.